# What am I doing wrong in the classing breaking the stick in 3 portions problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, puzzle

So I'm trying to solve the classic stick breaking problem, where it is given that we've a stick of length $9 units$ which is broken into 3 small sticks by putting two break points randomly.

What is the average length of the leftmost small stick?

So this is my approach :

let's say the first break point is put at a distance $x$ from the leftmost corner, assuming that this is the length of the left most small stick, the other break point must occur on the $(1-x)$ portion(on the right of first break point) of the stick.

```
        p0---------p1---------p2---------p3
```

So if we calculate the average length of $$p0->p1$$ and make sure that other break point lies on the right of $p1$ then we're done.

So the average length would be given by :

$$\int_0^9  \dfrac{x(9-x)}{9*9} dx$$

here

1. $(9-x)/9$ represents probability of the other break point lying beyond p1
2. $dx/9$ probability of first break point lying at p1
3. $x$ is the length of the first portion.

But this gives incorrect result.

By simple symmetry the answer should be $9/3$, which is $3$

but solving the above integral gives 1.5

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, although the distribution of both breaks are each independently and uniformly distributed on $[0,9]$, the distribution of the leftmost break is not uniform on $[0,9]$ as you have assumed.

To help you understand why, consider a discrete model for the rolling of two standard fair dice, each of which rolls an integer $D_1, D_2$ from $1$ to $6$ inclusive with equal probability.  What is the probability distribution for the *lesser* $\min(D_1, D_2)$ of the two dice rolls?  If we enumerate the outcomes, it becomes clear that $$\begin{align}
\Pr[\min(D_1, D_2) = 1] &= \frac{11}{36}, \\
\Pr[\min(D_1, D_2) = 2] &= \frac{9}{36}, \\
\Pr[\min(D_1, D_2) = 3] &= \frac{7}{36}, \\
\Pr[\min(D_1, D_2) = 4] &= \frac{5}{36}, \\
\Pr[\min(D_1, D_2) = 5] &= \frac{3}{36}, \\
\Pr[\min(D_1, D_2) = 6] &= \frac{1}{36}. \\
\end{align}$$

This is not uniform on the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, 6\}$.

Similarly, the distribution of the leftmost, i.e., the *lesser* of the two breaks of the stick, is not uniform on $[0,9]$.  If the two break points are $X_1, X_2$ and are continuous uniform random variables on $[0,9]$, then the random variable $$Y = \min(X_1, X_2)$$ is the location of the leftmost break.

One way to do the correct evaluation would be to write the expectation as a double integral over the joint continuous uniform density on $[0,9] \times [0,9]$:  $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \int_{x_1=0}^9 \int_{x_2 = 0}^9 \min(x_1, x_2) \cdot \frac{1}{9^2} \, dx_2 \, dx_1.$$  Since this integral is symmetric about $x_1 = x_2$, it is equivalent to $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = 2 \int_{x_1 = 0}^9 \int_{x_2 = 0}^{x_1} \frac{x_2}{81} \, dx_2 \, dx_1,$$ since by restricting the region of integration to $0 \le x_2 \le x_1 \le 9$, we always have $\min(x_1, x_2) = x_2$.  The rest is straightforward and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Ah yes, this makes perfect sense.